# Passing a php variable to a modal using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass a variable to my modal using AJAX but it's not working.

**PHP code**

```
echo '<img src="./images/see.png" class="open-modalPropietari" data-target="#modalPropietari" data-id="' . $id . '" >';
```

**JS code**

```
$(document).on('click', '.open-modalPropietari', function() {
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "propietaris.php",
                    data: {id: id},
                    success: function() {
                        $('#modalPropietari').modal('show');
                    }
                });
            });
```

it does execute the success (after 6-8 seconds) but it doesn't pass the variable.

I've looked at other posts on this forum but I can't find the solution.

Im pretty new at web development so I've no clue what's wrong.

Comment: What variable are you referring to?

Comment: what is the actual html markup of ` data-id="' . $id . '" >` when you view the source of the page in the console. Is it valid? When you inspect the post request what do you see being sent to the server?

Comment: What is the markup of the `img` tag when the page renders?  In what way does this fail?  You're not "passing a variable using AJAX" (which is an odd mix of terminology here), you're just rendering a page with a variable, sending that value back to the server, and then showing a modal (which has nothing to do with the variable).  When you debug this, where does it fail?

Comment: console.log(id) before $.ajax call, and var_dump($_POST) on server side for debug

Comment: the var_dump returns "array(0) { } ", and i tried to see the id before the ajax call, and it's showing the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**  It seems you wrote your question wrong so Ill try helping to debug:

First replace your $.ajax with this

```
  $.post( "propietaris.php", { id: id })
  .done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
  }).fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
  });
```

And `var_dump($_POST);` in your `propietaris.php`

When post is succesfull your console will show the post result page.  See if it contains your postdata.

Comment: actually it's echo '<img src="./images/see.png" class="open-modalPropietari" data-target="#modalPropietari" data-id="' . $id . '" >';

Comment: var_dump still "array(0) { } "

Comment: nvm: The vardump array must be seen AFTER post, Now you probably see it before POST.  So do a `var_dump($_POST);`.  Change console.log("succes") to `console.log(data)`  This will show your return page after post in console.

Comment: yeah including your vardump somewhere...what does it say? If it contains your postvar, it worked.

Comment: Good ;) So youve succesfully sent the id from php->html from html->php  ;)

Comment: Thank you for all your help, but I still don't know how to retrieve the variable on my modal

Comment: try in prop.php fisrtline: `if(isset($_POST['id'])){die($_POST['id'])}`   And in JS $('#modalPropietari').html(data);$('#modalPropietari').show();